# Resolving path that contains markdown files using require.context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, markdown

I wanted to get a list of all markdown files inside the `posts` folder using require.context

This is how I'm doing it inside `blog.js`:

```js
const req = require.context('../posts', true, /\.md$/);
const posts = (ctx => {
    const keys = ctx.keys();
    const values = keys.map(ctx);
    const data = keys.map((key, index) => {
        // Create slug from filename
        const slug = key.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
        const value = values[index];
        // Parse document
        const document = matter(value);
        return {
            document,
            slug
        };
    });
    return data;
})(req);
```

My folder structure is:

```
-config.js
-pages
  -blog.js
-posts
  -post-1.md
  -post-2.md
```

I'm getting error using this, apparently going up one folder is not allowed in require.context.
You can only go forward not back so double dot `../` is not permitted.

`TypeError: expected input to be a string or buffer`

How do I access the posts folder?

Comment: webpack? if so why you want to go one folder up? isn't `wepback` on your root?

Comment: Have you tried using `'/posts'` instead of `'../posts'`? Maybe all the paths start at the root directory.

Comment: @programmerRaj it doesn't start at root. `require.context` starts at whatever directory you used it, in this case, in `blog.js`

Comment: just checked out `webpack` docs, this is an example on docs: `require.context('../', true, /\.stories\.js$/);` so it does support parent directory. `TypeError: expected input to be a string or buffer` seems to be a type error, so most probably the problem is not with this line of code.

Comment: i know it may be oblivious but also consider googling error message with your context (webpack) : `webpack + type error : expected input to be a string or buffer`

Comment: @yaya you're right about the error coming form something else. closing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require.context allows going up one folder `../`

The error was coming from

`const document = matter(value);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use import instead of require.

import {Post-1, Post-2} from './posts';

Comment: i am using a loop to parse through all markdown files. Importing it one by one is not feasible